# Haxe Flash Socket connecting to Node.js with HTML5

Tags: sockets, haxe

I am switching over from Flash to HTML5, and I am having trouble connecting my socket over from the browser in HTML5 to Node.js.

For example, I get this error in the Firefox debugger:

```
The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:2500/ was interrupted while the page was loading. 
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:2500/.
```

In Haxe, I am using the import: flash.net.Socket;

It seems to attempt to connect to the Node.js server, however the data I am receiving is not what I want:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:2500
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The above is from the Node.js server.

Also, the event listener EVENT.Connect is not being called since no connection is happening.

Any suggestions? Is there a way to connect to a Node.js server in HTML5 with Haxe? I am using Haxe just for the sockets, I am not creating a server in Haxe.

Comment: Typically classes under the `flash.*` package are only available for the Flash target (Haxe compiling to as3 or SWF.) If you're switching to HTML5 (Haxe compiling to JavaScript), I would think you'd be using `js.html.WebSocket`, right? Or am I misunderstanding your stack?

Comment: You are right thank you very much. It is indeed js.html.WebSocket. I figure because the import worked that I could just use Socket. But it turns out that I need to be watching what platforms I am on. I am currently translating code from AS3 to Haxe as per the announcement of Flash being killed off soon.

Comment: There's a lib that tries to abstract platform specific websockets so that you don't have to yourself: https://github.com/soywiz/haxe-ws